# IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis, tomcat5.5

I am following the example in the link

[WS Example](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html)

After I start the server I get the error

```
IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
  axis-admin failed with  {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) http://localhost:8080/Axis2WSTest/services/AdminService
```

I tried using EClipse Galileo , Ganymede

Tomcat 5.5 and 6.0.35

axis2-1.6.2-bin

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: The error message shown is an Axis 1.x error, not an Axis2 error.

Answer (score 1):

Web Service->Configuration->Web Service Runtime, choose axis2 instead of axis.